# Alasql -Multiple sheetids within single promise statement

Tags: javascript, future, alasql

I am trying to call multiple sheets from the excel file ,by implementing single promise statement but it always outputs the data of first sheet.
Thank you.

```
    alasql.promise('select * from xls("raw/food.xls",[{sheetid:"Data"}, {sheetid:"Guideline"}])')
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Error:', err);
        });
```

Need to call both sheets data using single promise statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more than one promise, so try this:

```
alasql.promise(['select * from xls("raw/food.xls",[{sheetid:"Data"}])','select * from xls("raw/food.xls",[{sheetid:"Guideline"}])'])
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function (err) {
console.log('Error:', err);
});
```

Here are some more [examples](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/promise#chain-of-promises)